# IOS - user interaction does not work in view loaded from Xib

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

I have problem with interaction within my view that was loaded programatically. When app’s running the view is displayed well, however all input fields are not responsible.

Here is code of my view(file's owner - CarView):

```
CarView.swift - @IBDesignable class CarView: UIView {
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit(){
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CarView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.bounds = self.myView.bounds
    myView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(myView)

} }
```

---

```
var carView : CarView = CarView()

@IBAction func carViewButton(_ sender: Any) {

view.addSubview(carView)

    carView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    carView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: carButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    carView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    carView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the XIB show connections for the `IBOutlets` and `IBActions`?

If so, try adding it manually by using a target instead of `IBAction`.